# How to prevent image listing in google search results

Tags: .htaccess, google-search, robots.txt, hotlinking

My website is all about images. Even though I've disabled some features that would allow the average user to download my images I want to prevent them from being indexed in Google search results (I guess this is the same with preventing hotlinking?) . I don't know if I have to do this using .htaccess or using robot-texts (or both)..
Thank you all in advance :)

**Is this the right code??:**

**I want only my domain, facebook and linkedin  to be able to hotlink my images.**

If you believe that this kind of code would cause any problems to my website I will be more than happy to follow your suggestions :)

**UPDATE: I used cPanel.**

Problem: I've updated my code. The thing is that the htaccess for hotlinking works only the second time I load the direct link. For example from google search results I can see the www.mydomain.com/images/dog.png and select view image. It will show me the image and I will be able to download it too.. It will be not visible only if I reload that same link.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://example.com/.*$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://example.com$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.example.com/.*$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.example.com$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://www.facebook.com/.*$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://www.facebook.com$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://www.linkedin.com/.*$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://www.linkedin.com$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://www.gmail.com/.*$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://www.gmail.com$      [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(jpg|jpeg|svg)$ http://www.example.com [R,NC]
```

**Should I add  a robot text file with this too?  (are google robot texts working?)**

```
User-agent: Googlebot-Image
Disallow: /*.gif$
Disallow: /*.svg$
Disallow: /*.jpeg$
Disallow: /*.png$
```

Comment: How can i check, my site is index on google?

Answer (score 0):

A robot.txt file should be sufficient, see here:
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35308?hl=en